# Terraform Glue trigger with variable number of actions

Tags: loops, terraform, aws-glue

I am creating a Terraform resource block, for an AWS Glue Trigger, like this:

```
resource "aws_glue_trigger" "first_trigger" {
  name          = "first_trigger"
  type          = "CONDITIONAL"
  workflow_name = "first_workflow"
  enabled       = true
  actions {
    job_name  = "job_a"
  }
  actions {
    job_name  = "job_b"
  }
  actions {
    job_name  = "job_c"
  }
}
```

As you can see, there are a number of `actions` in the block, three in this example. At some point I will want to make the resource block more general, covering several Glue Triggers. When I do, the number of actions will be different in different cases. So I need to find a way to make them variable.

I tried this:

```
resource "aws_glue_trigger" "first_trigger" {
  name          = "first_trigger"
  type          = "CONDITIONAL"
  workflow_name = "first_workflow"
  enabled       = true
  actions {
    count = length(var.jobs)
    job_name = "${var.jobs[count.index]["name"]}"
  }
}
```

The above var `jobs` refers to a .tfvars file that looks like this:

```
jobs = [
   {name="job_a"}
  ,{name="job_b"}
  ,{name="job_c"}
]
```

But that doesn't work. Terraform does not like the way I am trying to generalize the creation of the actions. It gives me the error `Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context`

Is there some other way to make a variable number of actions in my `aws_glue_trigger` resource block? Some other type of iterator than `count` that can make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html). It would look something like this (untested):

```
resource "aws_glue_trigger" "first_trigger" {
  name          = "first_trigger"
  type          = "CONDITIONAL"
  workflow_name = "first_workflow"
  enabled       = true
  
  dynamic "actions" {
    for_each = var.jobs
    content {
      job_name = actions.value.name
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the syntax is a little weird. Unlike a `for_each` in a resource, where you access the values using `each.key` or `each.value`, in a dynamic block `each` is replaced with the block name (in this case, `actions`). This is so that you can have nested dynamic blocks without `each` becoming ambiguous.

Comment: Yup! Thank you! (Except for the fact that my list of jobs is a `var.` not a `local.` this is the correct answer.) And thanks for the explanation of the unexpected syntax